# How to handle XSS in Code View Of Summer Note

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, summernote

If the data is saved from code view option of summer note with data as alert(123); and the form is edited alert is seen.Is there any call back that can be used to prevent such XSS cases in code view option

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is filtering on Iframe tags that is enabled. There is another tag list that is not enabled by default and which can be modified with a custom regex. [See their documentation here.](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#xss-protection-for-codeview)